# Laravel include a template with dynamic value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to include a template dynamically eg: `@include('{{ site('theme') }}.header')`

but this throws up an error, how can I do this? (If I output `{{ site('theme') }}` this holds a value of `test`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a file in `resources/views/test` called `header.blade.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write it like php code.

`@include(site('theme').'.header')`

Comment: perfect makes sense, I should have referred to the error properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@include(site('theme') . '.header')
```